# xpath: skip child node with an given id

Tags: xpath

I have to configure our enterprise search engine and the indexing of documents is done via xpath selectors.
In the current setup there is an xpath

```
.//div[@id='content']
```

Which selects basically all elements of the main part of a website. Meanwhile there is an additional div with a lot of nonsense included, so I tried to modify this xpath to skip this div-tag. I am struggling with the documentation regarding "not" but withou any luck so far.

```
<div id="content">
  <div id="i-want-this">
   ...
  </div>
  <div id="i-do-not-want-this">
   <span>foo</span>
  </div>
  <div id="i-want-this-too">
   ...
  </div>
</div>
```

While I see that the hints in the comments helped me so far, I still have an issue with child elements in the div-tag I want to skip. Let's say, there is a span-tag inside. If I select

//div[@id='content']/*[not(@id='i-do-not-want-this')]
my result still includes this span-content. So I guess, I need a query for all elements below id="content" which do not have a parent id="i-do-not-want-this". Right?

Comment: you want only odd numbers ?

Comment: nope. My usecase is an div-tag which contains several texts which are quite useful on the page itself, but totally useless if these texts are shown in the serps of our enterprise search

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use the following query. It will select all child elements which id is not `i-do-not-want-this`.

```xml
//div[@id='content']/*[@id != 'i-do-not-want-this']
```

or - the same logic - using the `ǹot()` function (thanks @paul_t)

```xml
//div[@id='content']/*[not(@id='i-do-not-want-this')]
```

---

**Update**

When I said *the same logic* then this isn't really correct. Pleases visit the comment from @IanRoberts

Comment: or `//div[@id='content']/*[not(@id='i-do-not-want-this')]`

Comment: @pault. Yes, and I think to remember that `ǹot()` is more portable. but I'm not sure at the moment.. have added the alternative to my answer. thanks!

Comment: Both `x != y` and `not(x = y)` will do the same thing in this case, but they are different if either `x` or `y` (or both) is a node set containing more than one node.  In that case `x != y` is true if there is any pair of nodes one from `x` and one from `y` that do not match (there may be other pairs that do match), whereas `not(x = y)` is true only if _no_ pair matches.